# v7 searchview overlapping issue

Tags: java, android, searchview

example to what kind of problem I am running into.

Let say I have 6 elements in a listview all in order from left to right [1,2,3,51,4,5].

When I search for 5 it displays "51" and "5". When I click on "51" it opens up "1". The problem is that the filtered list overlaps the listview that displays all the elements. I was wondering how I can fix this issue. I am using v7.widget.SearchView

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_recipe).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                lv.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                lv.setFilterText(newText.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: What kind of adapter do you use?

Comment: the standard arrayadapter

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

Comment: same result. clicking on first searched element opens up the first element in the listview

Comment: Could you post on item  selected method?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K9D5gB5t

Comment: Do you understand idea of my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you make mistake in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method. You take data by position from data list. The "position" is a position of clicked item on list. So if you filtered your list and click on first item the value of position will be "1". You have to take value from adapter which is corresponding to clicked position. You should take item from adapter like is shown in code below:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...

        String data = ((ExerciseDAO)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getTitle() ;

        ...
    }
});
```

If you have questions - just ask.

Comment: hey sweet man it finally worked. Thank you so much. I ran into this problems a few months and got no luck. Came back to work on my project and it finally works now.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad that I could help you :) Good luck

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What do you exactly want to do. Now you get proper object. It seems like different issue.

Comment: That's great, Good luck one more time.